# Python: Avoid using multiple nested for loops to iterate over strings

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a simpler way to iterate over multiple strings than a massive amount of nested for loops?

```
list = ['rst','uvw','xy']

for x in list[0]:
    for y in list[1]:
        for z in list[2]:
            print x+y+z

rux
ruy
...
tvx
tvy
twx
twy
```

Example list I really want to avoid typing writing loops for:

```
list = ['rst','uvw','xy','awfg22','xayx','1bbc1','thij','bob','thisistomuch']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need itertools.product:

```
import itertools
list = ['rst','uvw','xy','awfg22','xayx','1bbc1','thij','bob','thisistomuch']
for x in itertools.product(*list):
    print(''.join(x))
```

product returns all possible tuples of elements from iterators it gets. So

```
itertools.product('ab', 'cd')
```

will return a generator, yielding ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `product` function from `itertools`:

```
import itertools

lst = ['rst','uvw','xy']
[''.join(s) for s in itertools.product(*lst)]

# ['rux',
#  'ruy',
#  'rvx',
#  'rvy',
#  'rwx',
#   ...
#  'twx',
#  'twy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way? Definitely. Simpler? Maybe not...

I'm guessing it's because you don't necessarily know how many strings you'll have in your list.

What about:
    sl = ['abc','mno','xyz']

```
def strCombo(l,s=''):
    if(len(l)==0):
        return s
    elif(len(l)==1):
        return [(s+x) for x in l[0]]
    else:
        return [strCombo(l[1:],(s+x)) for x in l[0]]



final = []
for x in strCombo(sl)[0]:
    final = final + x
```